# ScalaTest2 cannot run unit-tests when dynamic.classpath is enabled in IntelliJ[12/13]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, classpath, scalatest

We've ran into a strange problem after upgrading our suite of unit-tests to ScalaTest2.0 (with Scala 2.10)
Now running all our unit-tests is very unreliable: sometimes the process hangs, sometimes we get false failures, and the reporting within IntelliJ is messed up (individual tests are not reported under the proper class name, etc.)

After some investigation, we nailed it down to the IntelliJ property `dynamic.classpath`. When set to `false`, the problem disappears and our unit-tests run fine, when set to `true` (even in a different project) the problem starts to appear.

The problem is that we need `dynamic.classpath` set to true, else IntelliJ is complaining that the command line is too long, with the following message:

```
Error running Unit Tests
Command line is too long. In order to reduce its length classpath file can be used.
Would you like to enable classpath file mode for all run configurations of your project?
```

see problem here: [IDEA 10.5 Command line is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381213/idea-10-5-command-line-is-too-long)
and [What does the dynamic.classpath flag do? (IntelliJ project settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853540/what-does-the-dynamic-classpath-flag-do-intellij-project-settings)

Any help appreciated (or maybe a workaround to the "command line too long" without using dynamic classpath?)

```
IntelliJ v13.0.2 (also happened with 12)
scala plugin v0.30.387
scala v2.10.0
scalatest v2.10-2.0
```