# Intellij error "Error running 'GlassFish "

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

i am getting this error upon compilation and i have no idea how to fix it.

Error running 'GlassFish 4.1.2'
                Command line is too long. In order to reduce its length classpath file can be used.

Please can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: It seems as if the number of runtime dependencies--which need to be on the class path in order to run the server--exceeds the allowable length of the command line. Have you tried listing the jars/classes you need in a file and passing the filename as a parameter to the server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48116684/104891

Comment: hey guys, thank you for the help. i ended up using netbeans instead and it was much easier over there