# JHipster gradle: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jboss, jhipster

> JHipster gradle: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger for single module project

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging" }
```

Pressing Refresh on gradle tab in Intellij does not change the result.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your dependency has not version. For example you can use `3.3.2.Final` version. `compile "org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final"`. Check this page for choose version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging.

Comment: same with version

Answer (score 3):

I use to have the same error. Here is how to reproduce it :

- Create a new application with JHipster with Gradle support
- Open it in IntelliJ
- Select a "shorten command line" to avoid [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381213/idea-10-5-command-line-is-too-long)
- Run the *App.java file

And how to fix it :

- Open the "Run/Debug Configuration"
- Check **Include dependencies with "Provided" scope**

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

`org.jboss.logging` is a lib that most of main libs like hibernate and spring are depend on it. So it's not for the dependency problem. Maybe you do something wrong in your application. I suggest you upgrade your jhipster project. It will correct your mistakes. For more information please visit this site: [how to upgrade jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/).