# Corda V4 Contract and Flow Test cases dosent run in IntelliJ on Windows

Tags: corda

I tried cloning and running test cases on this Corda V4 Sample on Windows 10:
https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example

It gives following error

```
Command line is too long. Shorten command line for Run Contract Tests - Kotlin or also for JUnit default configuration.
```

I tried this fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50857092/4627552
But it throws another error

```
'net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.example.contract.IOUContract'
```

Tests run perfectly fine on Unix (tried on Ubuntu).
Just creates a Issue on Windows

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

Here is the background:
[IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 EAP: Configurable command line shortener and more](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/10/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-configurable-command-line-shortener-and-more/)

In your IntelliJ project go to: Run->Edit Configuration

The Run/Debug Configurations form will appear:

[image: Run/Debug Configurations Form]

Under the drop-down list beside "Shorten command line:" you can select either "JAR manifest" or "classpath file"

Both worked for me but I haven't done extensive testing.

Comment: Already tried that fix. Doesn't seem to work.
Issued raised in Corda: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4975

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradle test configuration in Intellij to run the tests.

In your IntelliJ project go to: Run->Edit Configuration

Click on the plus sign and Select Gradle. You can fill the details, in the Tasks field provide `:<modulename>:cleanTest:<modulename>:test`. For eg.`:contracts:cleanTest:contracts:test` and in the arguments field, you can specify `--tests "<test_name>"`