# Intellij 2021.2.3 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I'm using junit Jupiter 5.6.3 and receive following error when running a test. My SDK is Corretto 11.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor:org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor
```

My junit library is added to the module libraries. What does it mean NoClassDefFoundError? I assume the jar package is on the classpath.

[image: Junit dependencies]

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? What specific JUnit dependencies do you use? See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea.

Comment: Maven ... Added screenshot.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is happening because your commandline command is too long. I assume IntelliJ suggested you to use @argfile to shorten the command. Then when you ran it you encountered this exception. I had the same problem on Windows.

In my situation using JAR Manifest command shortener did not help. I solved it by moving my `C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository` to `C:\.m2\r`. This is making my classpath argument shorter for all dependencies.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78240460/3797224