# The command line is too long. in java project with maven

Tags: java, maven, command

I have maven-gwt project. It has lots of dependencies which is usual by a large project. I think it is at the limit with creation of classpath. I found some information about the limitation. Allowed is 1023 Character. But I need the libraries.

I receive the following error when i want to package my project mit `Maven`.

```
The command line is too long.
```

How can I get around the problem.?

Here is the expanded error in Jenkins:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Documents and Settings\User\.jenkins\workspace\Myproject\target\surefire-reports
The command line is too long.
The command line is too long.

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Comment: Which particular plugin is giving this error?

Comment: @matthew-farwell I got the error just after this line `--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) `

Comment: Can you post the whole error?

Comment: Actually your classpath limit does not seem to be true, If i execute `mvn dependency:build-classpath | wc -c` on a reasonably large project it says 10290... What is your output of `mvn dependency:build-classpath | wc -c` ? Who does add stuff to your classpath, maven or do you add it yourself?

Comment: @christian-uhl Eclipse or maven do it. What i changed in my code is just adding more dependencies. That was my auumption with classpath

Comment: I see this error with command too long only in jenkins. Eclipse say only `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) on project AuswertungsDB: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Workspaces_auf_C\GWT\ADB_Install\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] `

Comment: Try rerun with `mvn -X` for a more descriptive message before the failure. You might see which line is too long.

Comment: it tries to execute following:  `Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Programme\JAVA\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\java -classpath "MANY CLASSPATH PATHS.." org.apache
.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter C:\DOKUME~1\STL1309\LOKALE~1\Temp\surefire8733536338535403800tmp C:\DOKUME~1\STL13
09\LOKALE~1\Temp\surefire1935817605293835178tmp"` The problem it does not show the error in command shell only in jenkins

Comment: Are you able to run this line standalone `java -classpath "MANY CLASSPATH PATHS.." org.apache .maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter C:\DOKUME~1\STL1309\LOKALE~1\Temp\surefire8733536338535403800tmp C:\DOKUME~1\STL13 09\LOKALE~1\Temp\surefire1935817605293835178tmp"` from a cmd window?

Comment: Have you considered building on non-Windows? Every other desktop OS out there has _much_ higher limits on command line length, and running Linux in a VM is pretty easy…

Comment: it is not possible to execute from a command line. CMD doesn't allow after 8191 (2^13) characters.

Comment: if this error is given running the result of maven appassembler plugin, a simple solution is to specify absolute short <assembleDirectory> - in my case ${project.build.directory} ended up too long, i guess..

Comment: FYI: "_The command line is too long._" appears also with [`new DefaultInvoker().execute( InvocationRequest.setProperties( System.getProperties ) );`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/InvocationRequest.html#setProperties-java.util.Properties-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found another workaround here http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maven/issues/detail?id=88
(I have problem with changing pom to fit a specific OS)

In short: make path to local repository as short as possible.

"
Comment 40 by gaurav.a...@gmail.com, Mar 23, 2009
One of the fix to the problem of "GWT compilation fails due to- The input line is 
too long." is as follows:

1. Change m2(maven) repository. You might have your maven
   repository at:
         `C:\Documents and Settings\MahcineNameABC\.m2`
2. Copy settings.xml file from folder
       `apache-maven-2.0.8\apache-maven-2.0.8\conf` into `C:\Documents and Settings\MahcineNameABC\.m2`

   In **settings.xml**:
3. change the tag as 
        `<localRepository>M:</localRepository>`. Now your m2 home is a virtual M drive.
4. Create a repository folder as `D:\maven-2.0.8\repository`
5. Cut/Copy all the files/folders from `C:\Documents and Settings\MahcineNameABC\.m2\repository` to `D:\maven-2.0.8\repository`
6. Map local drive: open command prompt and execute (to create the
   virtual drive):
       `subst M: D:\maven-2.0.8\repository`([help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst))
   Now a virtual M drive will point to your repository.
7. Set environment variable `M2_REPO` with value M:
8. To enable long inputs, on command prompt execute:`cmd /e:32768`

This would fix the problem of long inputs due to very long entries in classpath 
variables, at least in Win XP SP2. The inputs are combined and tested from comment#22 
and #7.

Hope it helps!

This should help in most cases (and 'til the end of project - at least in my case)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known problem with gwt-maven. There is a discussion on the gwt-maven google groups: [Workaround for windows command line length limit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-maven/M1WqNHEe4IU)

The problem seems to be that the sources are included on the test classpath, hence you're getting problems when you're running surefire:

The workaround is to exclude the sources dependency, make it system scope (from the above thread):

```
    <dependency> 
        <!-- non existant artifact ID required (-source) maven bug?? --> 
        <artifactId>myproject-rpc-source</artifactId> 
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> 
        <version>${project.version}</version> 
        <classifier>sources</classifier> 

        <!-- hack below as maven only incudes provdied in test scope --> 
        <scope>system</scope> 
        <systemPath>${basedir}/../rpc/target/myproject-rpc-${project.version}-sources.jar</systemPath> 
    </dependency>
```

but I would fully read and understand the google groups thread before proceeding with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intellij there is a setting in workspace.xml that takes care of this issue.  There is an [existing post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853540/what-does-the-dynamic-classpath-flag-do-intellij-project-settings).

Answer (score -1):

From 2.5.0-rc1 the GWT Maven plugin has a new option: "genParam". Set this param to false to aviod this problem.

Comment: This parameter has nothing to do with the mentioned problem.