# "The command line is too long" -- when running maven test

Tags: java, maven, gwt, windows64

Running `$mvn test` on a 64-bit Windows gives me the following error, even if I do `$mvn test -Dgwt.genParam=false`:

```
The command line is too long
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181098/the-command-line-is-too-long-in-java-project-with-maven - is this related?

Comment: @Jayan Yes, its related but the answer there is not working

Comment: What version of the maven-surefire-plugin are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are using version `2.16` and that you have the `useManifestOnlyJar` option (as [documented](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useManifestOnlyJar) here).

For example:

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>

            <configuration>
                <useManifestOnlyJar>true</useManifestOnlyJar>
            </configuration>

          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

This will create jar with a manifest that re-creates your classpath (as opposed to setting it via the `CLASSPATH` variable which is an approach that is affected by Windows' command-line limit problem).