# Windows 11: Intellij IDEA [ERROR] PROTOC FAILED: The command line is too long

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, protoc

I am trying to build a maven project but when I am doing "mvn clean install" I am getting this error [ERROR] PROTOC FAILED: [0:0]:  The command line is too long. I am using Windows 11

I have already tried the solutions provided on
[IDEA 10.5 Command line is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381213/idea-10-5-command-line-is-too-long)
[The command line is too long. in java project with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181098/the-command-line-is-too-long-in-java-project-with-maven)
but it is not working

Comment: So, you already have "Shorten command line" option enabled, correct?
Can you run mvn -X clean install and post the output here?
EDIT: That actually looks like a PROTOBUF error. Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Apparently if you are trying to compile all the files in your project you get this error. After trying to compile just one .proto file i started getting a different error: "'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command". its like the compiler is not even there