# workspace corrupted grails 2.2.4, Intellij Idea 12.1.4, Windows 7

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Somehow my workspace is corrupted. When I try to run my app in the intellij IDEA I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\catalysts\sdks\grails\grails-2.2.4\grails-2.2.4 -Dbase.dir=C:\catalysts\src\mediacenter\mm-web "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\catalysts\sdks\grails\grails-2.2.4\grails-2.2.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -javaagent:C:\catalysts\sdks\grails\grails-2.2.4\grails-2.2.4\lib\org.springsource.springloaded\springloaded-core\jars\springloaded-core-1.1.3.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\bin" -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\lib\util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\Catalysts\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath4359768120270928639.tmp com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\catalysts\sdks\grails\grails-2.2.4\grails-2.2.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf run-app
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springsource/loaded/ri/ReflectiveInterceptor
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Test cases work fine, I also can start the app with run-app in the intellij console (CTRL+Alt+G).
I hope you might can help me.

Answer (score 12):

delete folder `~/.grails/.slcache`

Comment: I got this on 14.1 -- and the above worked for me. Andy my "dynamic.classpath" was already false.

Answer (score 8):

I recently was getting the exact same error (latest versions at this time: IDEA 14/grails 2.4.4). After fighting with it for a bit I recalled being asked a question earlier (by IDEA) something about the classpath, which I just blindly answered yes to.  Trying to find this setting led me to this question: [What does the dynamic.classpath flag do? (IntelliJ project settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853540/what-does-the-dynamic-classpath-flag-do-intellij-project-settings)

After editing my .iws file and setting dynamic classpath back to false the 'ClassNotFoundException: org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor' went away.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea needs to be upgraded to the last version