# Intellij how to disable classpath file mode for all run configurations of your project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Earlier I was having trouble running something and intellij threw this error. `Would you like to enable classpath file mode for all run configurations of your project?` I clicked enable. This did'nt solve my problem but now i cant seem to run anything from intellij. Where is this option in the settings so I can disable it?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5591427/1348743

Answer (score 8):

Set Ddynamic.classpath to true in the Intellij configuration file in the workspace or Add  `-Ddynamic.classpath=tr‌​ue` as a JVM argument.

Answer (score 6):

go to your project's root folder, there is .idea folder.
open workspace.xml file - search for "dynamic.classpath" property and change the value to false.