# How to configure default “Shorten command line” method (or other Run/Debug Configurations options) for all of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know how to set "Shorten command line" for specific configurations (eg a specific JUnit test configuration) and for specific configuration templates (eg for all new JUnit test configurations). Is it possible to configure IntelliJ IDEA to default to a specific setting (ie something set in `~/.IntelliJIdea*`) such that ALL configurations (eg JUnit, Cucumber, Spring Boot, etc) default to using that default method?

Comment: There is no global setting to control it, only [per project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853540/what-does-the-dynamic-classpath-flag-do-intellij-project-settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to set it for all configuration types but there is a way to set it as an IDEA default for specific configuration types.

First, in `~/.IntelliJIdea*/config/options/project.default.xml`, create a `<component name="ProjectManager"><defaultProject><component name="RunManager">…</component></defaultProject></component>` element if it doesn't already exist.

Then, for each configuration type to be defaulted:

1. Set a project default in a template for that configuration type in an existing project.
2. In that project's `.idea/workspace.xml` file, copy the `<configuration>…</configuration>` element inside the `<component name="RunManager">…</component>` element for that configuration type.
3. Paste that block into `~/.IntelliJIdea*/config/options/project.default.xml` inside `<component name="ProjectManager"><defaultProject><component name="RunManager">…</component></defaultProject></component>`.

Restart IntelliJ IDEA so all instances pick up the new defaults and don't overwrite `project.default.xml` thereby wiping out the settings.

Save `project.default.xml` in case exiting IntelliJ IDEA overwrote the modifications.