# Restriction in classpath length in Eclipse - Createprocess error=87, the parameter is incorrect

Tags: java, maven

Is may be duplicate of [Fail to launch application (CreateProcess error=87), can't use shorten classpath workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893970/fail-to-launch-application-createprocess-error-87-cant-use-shorten-classpath)

But still I'm wondering any workaround to fix the issue.
The issue is that, I'm using Eclipse and  have Maven projects with many classpath files(dependency) for the project.
When i try to run the program it gives "Createprocess error=87, the parameter is incorrect"
I know this is due to restriction of classpath length in Windows XP..

Is there way to specify to pick up the dependency in run time (Like dynamic classpath in Intellij) in Eclipse??

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated....

Comment: Does anyone has any updates or ideas or suggestions on the above issue..??/?

Comment: Please post your solution of you have fixed this already. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Still i havent found valid solution. All i tried is to put the maven dependency in different folder(which has less characters of actual path) than default location.