# can't build a ant target in TFS location

Tags: java, web-applications, ant, tfs

I have a ant target, xml file in my TFS project folder. the project folder is bound with TFS(Team Foundation Server). My problem is when ever i try to build the project by running the ant target in that TFS bound location it fails. it gives the following failure.

```
> ria_ant_build.xml:435: Error running C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javac.exe  compiler
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.
java:508)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:61)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javac.exe": CreateProcess erro
r=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.
java:505)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 24 more
```

**but when i copy the project to a different location and remove the read only attribute from the folder the ant target runs without any error and I'm getting a deploy-able artifact.** but even when i remove the read only attribute from the TFS folder i could not build the ant target.It seems like the problem exist on the TFS location it self. :(

can some one suggest me a method to solve this problem. I have to stay in the TFS location you guys know the reason i assume :)

--
Thanks & Regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's hard to figure out what really causes your problem.

Perhabs, your ant call length is too long and even longer than the max command prompt line (that's 8191 characters in the latest versions of Windows). As question [Fail to launch application (CreateProcess error=87), can't use shorten classpath workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893970/fail-to-launch-application-createprocess-error-87-cant-use-shorten-classpath) says you may consider "to shorten folder names, reduce depth of folder trees, using parameter files, etc".

Try to run **ant** with the **-debug** option to see the specific command-line parameters of your build call inside the TFS workspace. In that way you can estimate the total length of the call.

Comment: I was getting the error javac.exe  compiler, with the -debug option; I was able to see it was a "too long path" error.